# UIImageView setFrame: not working in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I've an `UIImageView` in customized `UITableViewCell` and I want to resize it, I set it view mode to LEFT. To resize I'm applying below code.

```
[cell.IBImage setFrame:CGRectMake(201,12,50,20)];
```

My image width is 100 and I want to reduce is to 50 but it still shows me in 100 width. If I set view mode to `Scale To Fill` it works fine but I want to have it's view mode to LEFT.

Full method cellForRowAtIndexPath is as given below:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DetailCell";

DetailCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DetailCell" owner:self options:nil];

cell = (DetailCell *)[topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];

clsDetailResponse *Response = [self.Histories objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

[cell.IBUsernameLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", Response.Firstname, Response.Lastname]];

[cell.IBImage setFrame:CGRectMake(201, 12, 50, 20)];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: where are you resigning..after loading image in lazy loading tech

Comment: @Rajneesh071 sorry I didn't get your question...

Comment: where are you resizing it..please provide some more code

Comment: @Rajneesh071 I'm resizing it in  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath , it works fine if i set view mode to Scale To Fill the problem is only with the view mode LEFT

Comment: can you paste code of cellforrow

Comment: @Rajneesh071 I've added please check...

Comment: and what is code where you are making IBImage

Comment: @Rajneesh071 I just created it in nib file. One more thing it's actual size is 100 even if i change it from nib file it automatically resized to 100

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21176/discussion-between-rajneesh071-and-mohit-mehta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing to resize the imageView frame not the image so You can crop your image as you want,

```
UIImage *ima = cell.image.image;
CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50,20);
CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([ima CGImage], cropRect);
[cell.image setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
cell.image.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 20);
```

Answer (score 1):

set IBImage frame in DetailCell class in

```
-(void)layoutSubviews:
```

method

Comment: It'll not be possible as width is dynamic and is decided in the method cellForRow... method

Comment: pass that dynamic width to DetailCell class, and use that passed parameter in layOutSubviews method.

Comment: DetailCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
cell.IBImageWidth = your width; and in layoutSubViews method of DetailCell class , [IBImage setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,IBImageWidth,height)],where IBImageWidth is a property of type int in detailCell class

Comment: Thanks Vishal but it's still not working... the problem is with the image view mode LEFT otherwise it's working

Comment: image view mode LEFT means?? your imageview's width is getting changed now?

Comment: in UIImageView there's a mode that how do you want it to scale... e.g. scale to fill, aspect fit, left, center, right etc.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to the File's owner to make sure it knows how to respond to framechanges.

```
    [self setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
    [self setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [self setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
```

Comment: Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: Add those three lines in the `initWithNib` or `awakeFromNib` method of your `DetailCell` class, depending on the structure.